# If $G$ is a group that acts on a finite set $X$, prove that there exists an integer$ N>0$, such that $g^{N}x=x$ for all $x\in X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, permutations, group-actions, group-homomorphism

**If $G$ is a group that acts on a finite set $X$, prove that there exists an integer$ N>0$, such that $g^{N}x=x$ for all $x\in X$**

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to write this proof for my course. I don't really understand the concept of groups acting on sets, so I'm trying to review my notes and textbook but it's not really clicking. I was given the hint that the action of $G$ on $X$ can be seen as a morphism from $G$ to $Perm(X)$, the permutation group of $X$. So the action of a fixed $g \in G$ permutes the elements in $X$.

In my notes I have that if a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, then it satisfies:

- $e_gx=x \forall x \in X$
- $(gh)x=g(hx), \forall g,h \in G, \forall x\in X$

I also have that one property of this is:

- $T:G\rightarrow Perm(X)=${$f:X\rightarrow X$ | $f$ bijective}, $T(g)(x)=T_g(x)=gx$, T is a morphism of groups.

I know that a homomorphism of groups preserves identities such that $T(e_G)=e_X$, so I'm assuming that I want to either show that

- $g^N=e_G$ such that $g^Nx=x \iff e_Gx=x$.

Or

- The action of $g^N \in G$ on $x \in X$ permutes the element $x$ in such a way that we get $e_Xx$ or simply $x \in X$.

I'm trying to connect the dots, but am not sure if I'm even working with the correct dots. Any sort of guidance or helpful insight would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure the quantifiers are clear.  What's $g$?  Is $N$ supposed to work for all $g$ simultaneously or can there be a different $N$ for different group elements $g$?

Comment: trying to think about it -- what if we take $N = |G|$ then $g^N = e_G$ so your relationship would hold?

Comment: The action may be viewed as a group homomorphism $T:G\to Perm(X)$ (usually this finite group "$Perm(X)$" is denoted $S_X$ or $\mathfrak S_X$). Since the subgroup ${\rm im}(T)$ is finite  (even if $G$ is infinite), its exponent is finite. Or simply, take $N=|S_X|=|X|!.$

Comment: @gt6989b can we assume that if $G$ isn't explicitly finite?

Comment: No you cannot. So: use my hint.

Comment: @AnneBauval That makes more sense to me, I wasn't sure if I could substitute "$Perm(X)$ as $S_X$. Thank you for this!

Comment: Alternatively, as $X$ is finite, the sequence $x,gx,g^2 x, \dots$ must eventually repeat itself. so you get $g^a x=g^b x$ for some distinct $a$ and $b$ and can use the inverse of $g$ to cancel to $g^{b-a} x = x$.

Comment: @ZoeAllen how would you know in your example that $b-a$ works for all $g \in G$?

Comment: @gt6989b I appear to have misinterpreted the order of quantifiers. It still works, you just need to take the sequence of $g^n(x_1 , \dots , x_k)$ for all $n$, and it still has to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is a finite set, suppose $X$ contains $n$ distinct elements $X=\{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}$ and consider the set $Y$ of all permutations on n-tuples $(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)$. Define: $$g(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)=(gx_1, gx_2,...,gx_n)$$

It is easy to check:

$(g_1g_2)(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)=g_1(g_2(x_1, x_2,...,x_n))$ and $e(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)=(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)$

So, $Y$ is a $G$-set. Now, for $\forall g\in G$, since $|Y|=n!$, if we consider the following elements $(e=g^0)$:

$g^0(x_1, x_2,...,x_n), ~~g^1(x_1, x_2,...,x_n), ~~g^2(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)..., ~~g^{n!}(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)$

There are totally $n!+1$ elements but at most $n!$ of them are distinct, which means there must be at least two of them are identical. Therefore, $\exists 0\le k_1< k_2\le n!$, such that $g^{k_1}(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)=g^{k_2}(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)$, which gives:

$$g^{k_2-k_1}(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)=(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)$$

Further,

$$g^{k_2-k_1}x_i=x_i, ~~i=1,2,...,n$$

Now we can let $N=k_2-k_1$, where $1\le N\le n!$, such that

$$g^{N}x=x, \forall x\in X$$